# Is there a way to pass down props to a component implicitly?

Tags: reactjs, redux, higher-order-functions

I'd like to be able to set a global theme (set of variables) for all of my components to inherit from and extend their default variables. For example, I have a `button` component that has default styles (inline CSS) that refer to a set of variables such as `primaryColor`, ... and I'd like to be able to update these variables easily wherever I use these components without needing to explicitly pass them to the components.

For example, I'd like the following behavior where I could either (1) wrap them in a component and have `primaryColor` cascade down to each `Button` component or (2) export this component in a higher order component and feed update the props, etc... however, I cannot get ay of these methods to work. Perhaps, there is a better way or ...

(1)

```
render() {
  return (
    <Theme variables={{ 'primaryColor': 'red' }}>
      <Button />
      <SecondButton />
      <ThirdButton />
    </Theme>
  );
}
```

(2)

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Button />
      <SecondButton />
      <ThirdButton />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Theme(SampleComponent)
```

This method works, as it's, obviously, passed down explicitly to each component:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Button variables={{ 'primaryColor': 'red' }} />
      <SecondButton variables={{ 'primaryColor': 'red' }} />
      <ThirdButton variables={{ 'primaryColor': 'red' }} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: why not just set them in your constructor? `import your_globals from 'somewhere'` then in your constructor... `this.options = your_globals`... then in the render you can use `this.options.primaryColor`

Comment: Each of these components will be sitting in their own `npm` packages so they cannot reference some global outside of their repo.

I was thinking of using the `context` within React to achieve this... not sure the viability of this approach.

Comment: well you didn't explain that in your question lol.. if they are separate npm packages it might just be worth it to make an npm package that the other ones use.. meaning if you had a package of a bunch of default options and styles you can make that a package and install it as a dependency on your other packages

Comment: Yeah my apologies! I should've been more clean. I'm already doing this with a global variables module that they all inherit from, but I'd like the ability to also override those variables from a top level component where I use these components. Hence, why I started using the `context` functionality.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can see a few ways that you might accomplish this:

### Extending child props

Limited, but allows passing 'extra' props to direct children of a component:

```jsx
import React, { Component, Children } from 'react';

class Theme extends Component {
  getChildren () {
    const { children, variables } = this.props;
    // Clone the child components and extend their props
    return Children.map(children, (child) => React.cloneElement(child, {
      variables
    }));
  }

  render () {
    return Children.only(this.getChildren());
  }
}

// Example
<Theme variables={{ 'primaryColor': 'red' }}>
  <Button />
  <SecondButton />
  <ThirdButton />
</Theme>
```

### React context

The easiest way to pass variables to any part of the React tree is by using context as described in the [React documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html) (this exact use case too!):

```jsx
// Context provider
class ThemeProvider extends Component {
  getChildContext() {
    return {
      theme: this.props.variables
    };
  }

  render() {
    return Children.only(this.props.children);
  }
}

ThemeProvider.childContextTypes = {
  theme: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

// HOC
function Theme(WrappedComponent) {
  class ThemeWrapper extends Component {

    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent { ...this.props } />;
    }
  }

  ThemeWrapper.contextTypes = {
    theme: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  };

  return ThemeWrapper;
};

// Using the HOC
class Button extends Component {
  render () {
    return <button style={{ color: this.context.theme.primaryColor }} />;
  }
}

const ThemeButton = Theme(Button);

// Example
<ThemeProvider variables={{ 'primaryColor': 'red' }}>
  <div>
    <ThemeButton />
  </div>
</ThemeProvider>
```

### Redux store

As you are using Redux, you could wrap each component that needs to be themed in the `connect` HOC and store your theme information in the store state. This is a simple way to share data and avoids the complexities of context:

```jsx
class Button extends Component {
  render () {
    return <button style={{ color: this.props.theme.primaryColor }} />
  }
}

const ConnectedButton = connect((state) => ({ theme: state.theme }))(Button);

// Example
// During app setup
store.dispatch(setTheme({ 'primaryColor': 'red' }));

// Later
<div>
  <ConnectedButton />
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

For anybody coming here post-hooks release, [here is an excellent guide](https://www.taniarascia.com/using-context-api-in-react/) on how to implicitly pass props via context and hooks. A quick summary of the article:

ThemeContext.js:

```js
const ThemeContext = React.createContext({});

export const ThemeProvider = ThemeContext.Provider;
export const ThemeConsumer = ThemeContext.Consumer;

export default ThemeContext;
```

HomePage.js:

```js
import {ThemeProvider} from './ThemeContext.js';

const HomePage = () => {
  const handleClick = e => {};
  const currentTheme = {backgroundColor: 'black', color: 'white'};
  return (
    <ThemeProvider value={currentTheme}>
      <MyButton text='Click me!' onClick={handleClick} ... />
      ...
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

MyButton.js:

```js
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import ThemeContext from './ThemeContext';

const MyButton = ({text, onClick}) => {
  const style = useContext(ThemeContext);
  return <button style={style} onClick={onClick}>{text}</button>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to create a higher order component ,you can refer to this http://gaearon.github.io/react-dnd/ but you still need to configure your component properly to determine something like if the props from higher-order component should apply or not.

Alternatively, why not create a wrapper component such as myButton

```
export default class MyBytton(){
   render(){
     return <button { 'primaryColor': 'red' } />
   }
}

render(){
   return <MyButton otherProperty:"foo"/>
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this would resolve the problem. As mentioned in the question, I've already implemented both the higher order component and the wrapped component via `children` but trying to see if I can get the global props to pass down without using `context`